# Raspicam library's frame rate and image

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I use raspicam library from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/). I can change frame rate at src/private/private_impl.cpp file. After the frame rate to 60, I can receive the frame rate 60, but the object size in the image is changed. I attached two images one is captured using 30fps and another one is captured using 60fps.
Why I have bigger object size using 60fps and how can I have normal object size (same as using 30fps)? 
The first image is usign 30fps and second image is using 60fps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to description [here](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/fov.html#camera-modes), the higher frame rate modes require cropping on the sensor for 8M pixel camera. At the default 30fps the GPU code will have chosen the 1640x922 mode, so gives full field of view (FOV). Exceed 40fps and it will switch to the cropped 1280x720 mode. In either case the GPU will then resize it to the size you requested. Resize a smaller FOV to the same size and any object in the scene will use more pixels.Can use 5M pixel camera if no cropping is required.

I should use Field of view, zoom or cropping rather than object size is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to keep the image the same size at higher frame rates by explicitly choosing a camera mode that does "binning" (which combines multiple sensor pixels into one image pixel) for both lower- and higher-rate capture.  Binning is helpful because it effectively increases the sensitivity of your camera.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/new-camera-mode-released/ for details when the "new" higher frame rates were announced.

Also, the [page in the other answer](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/fov.html#camera-modes) has a nice picture with the various frame sizes, and a good description of the available camera modes.  In particular, modes 4 and higher are binning, starting with 2x2 binning (so 4 sensor pixels contribute to 1 image pixel) and ending with 4x4 (so 16 sensor pixels contribute to 1 image pixel).

Use the `sensor_mode` parameter to the `PiCamera` constructor to choose a mode.